# Good way to reload React UseState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, random, react-hooks, render

So I need a useState() to change in order to rerender a certain component and it works. But I have to use a very ressource intensiv script for it. Is there a better way?

I want it like:

```
  const restartClick = (): void => {
    setDivClass("reload");
    setDivClass("loaded")
  };
```

This Worked but its not really good:

```
  const restartClick = (): void => {
    r = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
    setDivClass(r);
  };
```

I tried using diffrent Values increasing an integer paralel but this is also kinda unclean. I really would appreciate a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to trigger a render with your setState, and the value of the setState is not important, then try this :

```
  const [divClass, setDivClass] = useState(false);
  const restartClick = () => {
      setDivClass(!divClass);
  };
```

Comment: In Order for the other Scrips to work the setDivClass needs to stay a String, its getting passed down alot